# Address list in Outlook isn't syncing up with Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2010, exchange

As of recent I decided to open up active directory and clean up things a bit. i.e. removing contacts, users, and specific groups that are no longer used within the organization. After doing so I opened Exchange System Manager, dropped down All Global Address Lists and then right clicked and selected properties over default Global Address List. In previewing this list, this allowed me to see what would show up in our address list through Outlook. All the users and contacts I deleted prior to viewing this were not in the list. (Which is what I wanted).

However, all employees here are using Outlook 2010 and use the Global Address List on a regular basis. When viewing the global address list through Outlook 2010 all of the former users and contacts remained visible within the list. Its as if Outlook hasn't synced up or updated the list according to the Exchange server. How do I get the address list in Outlook to accurately show the addresses and contacts of Exchange Server?

Comment: You're not viewing the GAL when using Outlook(assuming cached mode is being used.)  You're viewing the OAB (Offline Address Book), which is a periodically generated version of the GAL.  It can up to 24 hours for a client to receive OAB updates.

Comment: Is there any way to advance this update manually?

Comment: The answer below will work.

Comment: @GMitch - Yes, Refer to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841273

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In outlook 2003/2007 click on tools -->send and receive -->download address book

This will solve the problem. Sadly you have to do this on each client. Outlook will do a perodic sync as well.  In outlook 2010 click on the send receive tab and click on download address book.